# Poster printing tip

Tags: printing, beamerposter, posters

I made a poster using Beamerposter and I am about to print it. A couple of places I have in mind asks to upload a file in a picture format. I have a couple of questions.

- Does latex support output as .tiff or any high quality image file?
- If not, what would be the best approach when converting a PDF to image?

Comment: No tiff-support. When converting from pdf (why is pdf not allowed?) make sure, the other format is a vector format like `svg`. Rasterizing it will *destroy* some of the nice work, if you are unlucky.

Comment: btw, the core of this question is *converting pdf to another format without loosing information*, so it might get transferred to another SE site.

Comment: You could use ImageMagick: `convert -density 60000 poster.pdf poster.tiff` But I would caution you *against* using any rasterized image format (like TIFF, PNG, JPG, etc.) Postscript would be a common denominator with your printer and would preserve the vector qualities of your poster.  The idea that your printer (the people printing the poster) won't accept PDF is more than a bit strange, though…